# How do I digitally sign an HTTPS request in .net?

Tags: .net, ssl, https, digital-signature

Is there a built in procedure to digitally sign an HTTPS request with client's SSL private key in .net? Also, is there a built in procedure to verify the digital signature against an SSL certificate? Or do I have to roll my own? Or is there a third party library?

The data that I want to sign is normal HTTP form request. For example I'm providing this address to deduct balance of a card:

```
https://myserver/deduction
```

The client will post an HTTP form to that address with data like card=1234567890123456, currency=1, amount=1000, etc. This data is the one I want my client to sign.

I need the request to be digitally signed because the client manipulates money, so I want to be sure that the request really comes from the client and that nobody tampers with the content of the request.

I'm also considering using SSL client certificate, but it can only provide confidentiality and authentication, but not data integrity.

Comment: Using X509Certificate2 with RSACryptoServiceProvider should do the trick. Can you explain a little about what kind of data you are trying to encrypt.

Comment: @Lars I have added more explanation to my question

Comment: why not just let your webserver, IIS, take care of the ssl encryption?

Comment: @Pauli actually my question is about digital signature, not encryption

Comment: ah, now i get it... kinda like signing with a certificate for authentication?

Comment: @Pauli yes, to prove that the sender is really my client and that the data is really what my client sent

Comment: Is this will helpfull for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649247.aspx ?

Comment: @apros that's for setting up SSL client certificate, which can help my case, but it doesn't digitally sign the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a whole example here with code how to do basic Digital Signature Implementation in C# http://tutorial.visualstudioteamsystem.com/details.aspx?item=134

```
var MySigner = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
string publicKey;

using (var file = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
    {
        var data = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);

        var signature = MySigner.SignData(data);

        publicKey = MySigner.ToXmlString(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + Convert.ToBase64String(signature));
    }
}

var verifier = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
verifier.FromXmlString(publicKey);

using (var file = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file)) 
    { 
        byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes((int)file .Length);

        if (verifier.VerifyData(data, signature))
            Console.WriteLine("Signature");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Signature is not verified");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. So in my case, first I must serialize my HTTP form data, and then sign the serialized string (IOW roll my own signing procedure)